# session is not destroying

Tags: php

i created a login page in php and used session in it... after checking the condition i am setting the session as

```
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
```

and in the     `login_succes.php` i have the code as

```
<? 
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<h2><?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['myusername']; ?>
Welcome to hell</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and in     `logout.php` the code is

```
<? 
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

the issue i am facing is on login 2nd time i am getting 1st user name itself in the output.

Comment: `session_register` is so pre-2000 …

Comment: Have you checked whether it’s just a cached response on the second request?

Comment: @knittl what can be solution for this?

Comment: @Gumbo can u elaborate how to do it

Comment: @S.A.Rahman: [`session_register`](http://php.net/session_register) is deprecated as of PHP 5.3 – you should directly access the super global `$_SESSION` instead.

Comment: You should put an exit; behind the header().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To destroy a session with one of the following:

```
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION);
```

Instead of session_is_registered, use standard $_SESSION super global. Like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))...
```

To register a session variable use:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
```

Also, PHP version, environment, could help us to find out.

Comment: To avoid warnings, you should use `isset` or `array_key_exists`.

Comment: You should use `if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))`.

Comment: php 5.3.9 and i m using apache

Comment: it should be     `$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;`
or      `$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;`